# Not able to create object of Excel.Application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

In my C# application i am importing and exporting data to excel. I have office 2013.

I am using following code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application _excelApp = null;
_excelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

This code was working fine but recently i installed Microsoft project professional 2013, it also update office. After this i am getting error in _excelApp = new Excel.Application();

Error is:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due
>   to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

Comment: Probably you need to remove existing office interop reference and latest version reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved. When i installed Microsoft project professional 2013, it also update microsoft office, but the updation of office was not successful.

When i repair office, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Deepak gupta, i can t comment so i post it here. Maybe Soner is right. I used to have the same problem so i decided to use the old way to open an Excel file (with an oledb command).

What do you need? Read an Excel or save a new one?

For example in my case i needed to read an Excel (that was and .xls or .xlsx):

```
               //Check whether file extension is xls or xslx
            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

            //Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command            
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            con.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();

            //send query, send query, fill adapter:
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "A1:GR255] WHERE [0] IS NOT NULL ";
            dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
            con.Close();
```

Or maybe you can try using this library ExcelLibrary that is described in this post [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

**This is way to create Object and thereby to copy the worksheet from One excel to another Excel**

Dim CopyFrom As  Object
        Dim CopyTo As Object
        Dim CopyThis As Object
        Dim xl As Object

```
    xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = False
    CopyFrom = xl.Workbooks.Open("E:\EXCEL\From.xls")
    CopyTo = xl.Workbooks.Open("E:\EXCEL\To.xls")
    For i = 0 To 1
        ''To use a password: Workbooks.Open Filename:="Filename", Password:="Password"
        If i = 0 Then
            CopyThis = CopyFrom.Sheets(1)
            CopyThis.Copy(After:=CopyTo.Sheets(CopyTo.Sheets.Count))
            CopyTo.Sheets(3).Name = "Sheet3"
        Else
            CopyThis = CopyFrom.Sheets(2)
            CopyThis.Copy(After:=CopyTo.Sheets(CopyTo.Sheets.Count))
            CopyTo.Sheets(4).Name = "Sheet4"
        End If
    Next
    CopyTo.Sheets(1).Activate()
    CopyTo.Save()
    'CopyTo.SaveAs("E:\EXCEL\Check.xls")
    xl.Quit()
```